Performance issues with time interval check
I'm running the following Postgres query where I join a consumer's usage with the service cost for that interval based on when they used the service from the service table. The query below is a truncated version, some times I have to do up to 12 or more joins. The issue is it can 2.5 minutes to run one query. How can I reduce this time? Am I taking the right approach?
select 
  c.consumption, 
  c.interval_start, 
  c.interval_end, 
  s1.value_exc_vat as service1_price, 
  s2.value_exc_vat as service2_price 
from 
  consumer as c 
  left join service1 as s1 on c.interval_start >= timestamp '2023-03-18T00:00:00Z' 
  and c.interval_start < timestamp '2024-02-15T00:00:00Z' 
  and (
    s1.payment_method is null 
    or s1.payment_method = 'DIRECT_DEBIT'
  ) 
  and c.interval_start >= s1.valid_from 
  and (
    c.interval_start < s1.valid_to 
    or s1.valid_to is null
  ) 
  left join service2 as s2 on c.interval_start >= timestamp '2024-02-15T00:00:00Z' 
  and c.interval_start < timestamp '2025-02-15T00:00:00Z' 
  and (
    s2.payment_method is null 
    or s2.payment_method = 'DIRECT_DEBIT'
  ) 
  and c.interval_start >= s2.valid_from 
  and (
    c.interval_start < s2.valid_to 
    or s2.valid_to is null
  ) 
order by 
  c.interval_start desc

I've isolated the issue to this section of the query in each join:
and c.interval_start >= s1.valid_from 
  and (
    c.interval_start < s1.valid_to 
    or s1.valid_to is null
  ) 

It seems finding the right interval to join the table takes a lot of time. The time periods can vary from 30 minutes apart to a couple of months or years for both the consumer and service tables so I can't do a simple c.interval_start = s1.valid_from and c.interval_end = s1.valid_to
Here is an EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS):
"QUERY PLAN"
"Sort  (cost=5523752586.99..5549030615.96 rows=10111211585 width=28) (actual time=140588.278..140589.028 rows=20593 loops=1)"
"  Sort Key: c.interval_start DESC"
"  Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 2216kB"
"  Buffers: shared hit=396"
"  ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=0.00..2633916836.23 rows=10111211585 width=28) (actual time=12.169..140546.307 rows=20593 loops=1)"
"        Join Filter: ((c.interval_start >= '2023-03-18 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (c.interval_start < '2024-02-15 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (c.interval_start >= s1.valid_from) AND ((c.interval_start < s1.valid_to) OR (s1.valid_to IS NULL)))"
"        Rows Removed by Join Filter: 559372220"
"        Buffers: shared hit=396"
"        ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=0.00..3979716.14 rows=4302977 width=24) (actual time=0.058..27617.147 rows=20593 loops=1)"
"              Join Filter: ((c.interval_start >= '2024-02-15 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (c.interval_start < '2025-02-15 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (c.interval_start >= s2.valid_from) AND ((c.interval_start < s2.valid_to) OR (s2.valid_to IS NULL)))"
"              Rows Removed by Join Filter: 176848172"
"              Buffers: shared hit=196"
"              ->  Seq Scan on consumer c  (cost=0.00..337.93 rows=20593 width=20) (actual time=0.007..21.813 rows=20593 loops=1)"
"                    Buffers: shared hit=132"
"              ->  Materialize  (cost=0.00..214.29 rows=8588 width=20) (actual time=0.000..0.272 rows=8588 loops=20593)"
"                    Buffers: shared hit=64"
"                    ->  Seq Scan on service2 s2  (cost=0.00..171.35 rows=8588 width=20) (actual time=0.006..0.891 rows=8588 loops=1)"
"                          Filter: ((payment_method IS NULL) OR (payment_method = 'DIRECT_DEBIT'::bpchar))"
"                          Buffers: shared hit=64"
"        ->  Materialize  (cost=0.00..675.37 rows=27164 width=20) (actual time=0.000..0.896 rows=27164 loops=20593)"
"              Buffers: shared hit=200"
"              ->  Seq Scan on service1 s1  (cost=0.00..539.55 rows=27164 width=20) (actual time=0.002..2.830 rows=27164 loops=1)"
"                    Filter: ((payment_method IS NULL) OR (payment_method = 'DIRECT_DEBIT'::bpchar))"
"                    Buffers: shared hit=200"
"Planning Time: 0.107 ms"
"Execution Time: 140590.312 ms"


The only way to improve WHERE xxx < yyy OR yyy IS NULL (except the very special cases) is to divide the query with one separate condition in each query, with further UNION ALL.

Can you please elaborate with an example?

Can you refactor to store a very large date, rather than NULL, in s2.valid_to?

If you already know what the problem is, you should simplify the example to focus just on that, and if you get the same slowdown then show an EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS) for it.

@jjanes I can't change the "valid_to" values in the table when they are null, but if it's possible to do it temporarily then that would be okay. Is that possible. I've attached the  EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS).

Are payment_method, valid_to etc. actually nullable, or did you add the ORs just for NULL values generated by the outer join? Without those pesky ORs, performance would be better.

@LaurenzAlbe They are nullable, a null valid_to is current. Why does OR cause performance issues? Should it be always avoided? When is best to use it?

OR often causes performance problems because it is difficult to compute: while AND restricts the result, OR adds additional rows. Avoid OR wherever you can.

I think you could replace
  and c.interval_start >= s1.valid_from 
  and (
    c.interval_start < s1.valid_to 
    or s1.valid_to is null
  ) 

with
and c.interval_start <@ tstzrange(s1.valid_from,s1.valid_to)

Which could then use an index
create index on service1 using gist (tstzrange(valid_from,valid_to))

By using a functional index, you would not need to refactor the table.
The range types, operators over them like <@, and indexing them with GiST indexes are explained a bit at https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rangetypes.html#RANGETYPES-INDEXING

Excellent, thank you so much. The search went from 2.5 mins to 600ms, thank God. Please can you add a bit more detail about what's happening? What is this <@ doing? And what is the value of adding using gist to create index?
